# Epson network printer

Tags: kubuntu, printing, epson

I installed the latest Kubuntu on a macbook air and I have an Epson ET-3750 printer that I'm trying to print on over the network.

On another machine I had the same problem, but I was able to fix it somehow using cups.  I replicated the cups settings from that other machine to my laptop and it still will not print.

My specific problem is this:
The printer installed automatically, and I can print from applications (I have successfully printed from Kate), but I can not print from a browser.  I have tried Brave and Firefox, and the printer shows an error in the cups log of:

```
E [07/Feb/2020:16:47:36 -0600] [Job 9] File \'\' not found
```

every time I try to print from a browser.

Is this a permissions problem?

The browser "printer" settings just takes me to the system printer settings, which work fine.  There is something going wrong from the browser to the printer.

Also, I can "print to file" and the file opens and prints from the pdf viewer no problem.

Comment: Please define 'latest'; specifically which release version number do you have?

Comment: `grep "''"` in all of your " replicated" CUPS settings.

Comment: my version is Kubuntu 19.10

Comment: not sure which file to grep, I manually added the CUPS settings to the CUPS webadmin.  Here's what the cups error log says each time I try to print from the browser: E [07/Feb/2020:16:32:37 -0600] [Job 8] File \'\' not found
E [07/Feb/2020:16:32:40 -0600] [Job 8] Unable to add document to print job.
E [07/Feb/2020:16:47:36 -0600] [Job 9] File \'\' not found
E [07/Feb/2020:16:51:18 -0600] [Job 10] File \'\' not found
E [07/Feb/2020:16:51:21 -0600] [Job 10] Unable to add document to print job.
E [07/Feb/2020:16:52:46 -0600] [Job 11] File \'\' not found